# AngularJS $http request not getting detect as xhr in Node JS Express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am using $http in AngularJS to call Node JS Express API

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: '/list',
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){
    console.log('then1');
});
```

But in Node JS ('/list') while I am checking is it xhr request, return false.

```
console.log('IS XHR ' + req.xhr) // IS XHR false
```

I need to detect if xhr request then do something else, how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the `X-Requested-With back` to `$httpProvider` in your angularjs application like below, but it has been removed by angularjs team... https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3a75b1124d062f64093a90b26630938558909e8d

Like below:

```
var app = angular.module('yourApp', []);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers
               .common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
}]);
```

OR

```
$http.get('/list', {
  headers: {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
  }
});
```

You can try something like below:

```
if (req.xhr || req.headers.accept.indexOf('json') > -1) {
  //xhr response
  } else {

}
```